# Multi select box selection list issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two select boxes left and right boxes which have some options and have two buttons one to move options from left to right select box and other to move from right to left. I am facing these issues.

1. When I click on a button "<<"  that copies content to left from right the append method is called.Selected item gets added to left but is removed from right.

I want the item to be retained at the right frame and still be added to left as well.

Second Issue is. I Populate the left frame with some selection.
Now when I add an item from right to left it will check and won't allow addition if already exists

Right Select box values [A,,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L]
Left select box values  [ D,E,F,G]  [PREPOPULATED VALUES ]

If user try to add again existing values I.e value  D or E etc into left frame it won't allow and warns a user

If user clicks and try to move from left to right that will be removed from left not appended to right. remove function is called

But if user  try same operation ie Add non-existing entry eg: L into the left frame it will allow addition...but if again moved from left to right it will be removed.

```
$(function(){

          // button to move elements from right to   left

     $("#btnLeftw").click(function () {
          var selectedItem = $("#rightValues option:selected");
          var selText = selectedItem.val();      


          if ( ($("#leftValues option[value='"+selText+"']").length )<= 0 )
              {

            $("#leftValues").append(selectedItem);  

          else
              {
              alert("Selected Memeber is already added"+($("#leftValues option[value='"+selText+"']").length ));
              }
        }); 


   // button to move elements from left to   right
   $("#btnRightw").click(function () {            
     var selectedItem = $("#leftValues option:selected"); 
     var selText = selectedItem.val();    

            if ( ($("#rightValues option[value='"+selText+"']").length )<= 0 ) // if item not in right select add it
                 {

                 $("#rightValues").append(selectedItem);


              }
         else
              {

                   selectedItem.remove();  // if already exist in right select just remove from left
              }

   });









<section>
 <div>
         <div>
            <input type="text" id="txtLeft" disabled="disabled"  value="myteam"/>
        </div>

        <select id="leftValues" name="leftValues" size="11" multiple>
               <option value="1">D</option>
               <option value="2">C</option>
               <option value="3">E</option>
                <option value="4">F</option>   


</select>

 </div>
  <div c>
    <div> 
         <br>  <br>  <br>
          <input type="button" id="btnLeftw" value="&lt;&lt;" />
         <input type="button" id="btnRightw" value="&gt;&gt;" />

    </div>
    </div>


    <div class="mySECTIONdiv">
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="txtRight" disabled="disabled"  value="Team Master List"/>
        </div>
        <select id="rightValues" name="rightValues" size="10" multiple> 

               <option value="1">A</option>
               <option value="2">B</option>
               <option value="3">C</option>
                <option value="4">D</option>  
               <option value="5">E</option>
               <option value="6">G</option>
               <option value="7">H</option>
                <option value="8">I</option>  
                 <option value="9">J</option> 
                  <option value="10">K</option>          

        </select>        
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Post your code as well so it will be better.

Comment: Stackoverflow coding standards is like: let's just put some random spaces here and there! It's our coding standard! #content

Comment: If you want to copy element then use `.clone()` like `$("#leftValues").append(selectedItem.clone());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to copy element then use `.clone()` like `$("#leftValues").append(selectedItem.clone());`.

Test code below.

```js
// button to move elements from right to left
$("#btnLeftw").click(function() {
  var selectedItem = $("#rightValues option:selected");
  var selText = selectedItem.val();
  if (($("#leftValues option[value='" + selText + "']").length) <= 0) {
    $("#leftValues").append(selectedItem.clone());
  } else {
    alert("Selected Memeber is already added" + ($("#leftValues option[value='" + selText + "']").length));
  }
});


// button to move elements from left to right
$("#btnRightw").click(function() {
  var selectedItem = $("#leftValues option:selected");
  var selText = selectedItem.val();
  if (($("#rightValues option[value='" + selText + "']").length) <= 0) // if item not in right select add it
  {
    $("#rightValues").append(selectedItem);
  } else {
    selectedItem.remove(); // if already exist in right select just remove from left
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="txtLeft" disabled="disabled" value="myteam" />
    </div>

    <select id="leftValues" name="leftValues" size="11" multiple>
      <option value="4">D</option>
      <option value="3">C</option>
      <option value="5">E</option>
      <option value="6">F</option>
    </select>

  </div>
  <div c>
    <div>
      <br> <br> <br>
      <input type="button" id="btnLeftw" value="&lt;&lt;" />
      <input type="button" id="btnRightw" value="&gt;&gt;" />

    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="mySECTIONdiv">
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="txtRight" disabled="disabled" value="Team Master List" />
    </div>
    <select id="rightValues" name="rightValues" size="10" multiple>

      <option value="1">A</option>
      <option value="2">B</option>
      <option value="3">C</option>
      <option value="4">D</option>
      <option value="5">E</option>
      <option value="7">G</option>
      <option value="8">H</option>
      <option value="9">I</option>
      <option value="10">J</option>
      <option value="11">K</option>

    </select>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I  used the clone statement and did meet a part of my requirement . Thanks Karan